# how to change java environment variable on windows

Tags: java, environment-variables

I installed java 7 on windows xp.

Test was ok:

```
C:\Users\nlel>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I added system variables for `JAVA_HOME`:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

I need to change to 1.6 version I installed 1.6 version and changed system variable for java home:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

at `PATH` I have next:

> %JAVA_HOME%terminal\bin

but after restarting console with PC I keep having the same java version after checking:

```
C:\Users\nlel>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
....
```

***Update:***

Now with suggestions it looks next:

```
C:\Users\nlel>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windo
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspers
rity 8 for Windows\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Pro
e\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.
 Files (x86)\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\;C:\Program F
\\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\tools\utils;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.
ndows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Sy
werShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky En
8 for Windows\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Program
che-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.3/bin
s (x86)\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\;C:\Program Files
;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\tools\utils

C:\Users\nlel>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

C:\Users\nlel>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

And `javac -version:`

```
C:\Users\nlel>jav
javac 1.6.0_45
```

Why exactly this happen?

Comment: Please reply with the results of `echo %PATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin;%PATH%
java -version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but after restarting console with PC I keep having the same java
>   version after checking:

It seems that you used `set` in order to set the environment variable.  Saying

```
set FOO bar
```

would set the variable `FOO` to `bar` only for the current terminal.  If you open another terminal window, you wouldn't see the change.

In order to make the change permanent, use `setx`:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
setx Path "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%"
```

Comment: do I need to type it at console? It's windows...

Comment: @nazar_art Yes, on the console (command prompt).

Comment: @ after second command it prints: `C:\Users\nlel>setx Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.`

Comment: @nazar_art There was a typo.  Fixed now, see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You say you added system varaible `JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`
And you added to Path: `%JAVA_HOME%terminal\bin`

so you have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\terminal\bin` in your path. and it points to java 1.7
You should change your JAVA_HOME varaible.

And one more thing, I didnt understand what is `terminal` after your `%JAVA_HOME%` . I think you should double check it.